# Why Fragment/Activity layout looks bad when changing device language to RTL languge?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-xml

I built an application (for practice Android), and i use *start*, *end* in order to support both **LTR** and **RTL** languages. I also set *android:supportsRtl="true"* in manifest file.
When device is set to **LTR** language all text looks great, and alignment great to the left. **But**, when changing device language to **RTL** language, all text seems bad and isn't alignment to the right (maybe some of the *TextView* are alignment and some aren't). In addition it seems that the **Spinner** *view* is totally **Wrong**. I have attached two screen shot (for both languages). I'm asking for your help, because i don't understand what i'm doing wrong. 
Also attached 3 code snipping (one for all the layout, the second for the item inside the RecyclerView and the third the item for the Spinner:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:dropDownWidth="120dp"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="96dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.example.currencyconvertor.MultiButton
        android:id="@+id/multiButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:activeButtonIndex="0"
        app:backgroundSelector="@drawable/multi_button_background_selector"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner"
        app:numOfButtons="2"
        app:reversedOrder="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:textColorSelector="@drawable/multi_button_text_color" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/multiButton"
        tools:text="TextView1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Symbol"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView1"
        tools:text="TextView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_goneMarginEnd="3dp"
        tools:text="TextView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="TextView4" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        tools:listitem="@layout/relative_currency_rate_row" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code for RecyclerView item:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="@color/rowColor"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/targetCountryTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


                <ImageView android:id="@+id/countryFlagImageView"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/container"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:paddingEnd="4dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/currencyTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/countryFlagImageView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="USA"
                    android:textColor="@color/currencyRowTextColor"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/targetCountryTextView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rateTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="Dollar"
            android:textColor="@color/currencyRowTextColor" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rateTextView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/targetCountryTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="0.417"
            android:textColor="@color/currencyRowTextColor"  />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code for Spinner item:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/rowColor">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flagImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/countryTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_glag"
        android:textColor="@color/currencyRowTextColor"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/flagImageView"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/currencyRowTextColor"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currencyTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/countryTextView"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="countryCurrencyTextView"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/currencyRowTextColor"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_drop_down"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: LTR]

[image: RTL]

Comment: Can someone tell me what is wrong in my question,so no one wants or can answer it? If someone tell me i will elaborate it cause i'm desperate for a help :(

Answer (score 0):

disable supports RTL on your manifest file:

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="false">
```

I hope to be useful ;)